# How to find a breakpoint for each ID in a linear regression model with R?

Tags: r, piecewise-linear

I have some repeated measures with 196 individuals and some of my regressions have a plateau. So I want to characterize this with an eventual breakpoint for each ID.

Example: subset of my personal data

```
 ID     time   y
7G009   0       9
7G009   108,33  13
7G009   185,69  16
7G009   309,22  20
7G009   515,08  21
7G051   0       10
7G051   108,33  14
7G051   185,69  19
7G051   309,22  23
7G051   515,08  25
8S027   0       8
8S027   108,33  13
8S027   185,69  17
8S027   309,22  22
8S027   515,08  23
```

I have tested with the `strucchange` package (`breakpoint()`), or with the `segmented` package (`segemented()`). I have also tried with the `siZer` package (`piecewise.linear()`); it’s OK with one ID, but I am stuck when I want to deal with all my IDs.

My first attempt was with using the code in the review named [segmented: An R Package to Fit Regression Models with Broken-Line Relationships](http://ftp.csie.ntu.edu.tw/pub/R/CRAN/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2008-1.pdf#page=20) by Vito M. R. Muggeo. Cf page 23:

```
> data("plant")
> attach(plant)
> X<-model.matrix(~0+group)*time
> time.KV<-X[,1]
> time.KW<-X[,2]
> time.WC<-X[,3]
```

But I am stuck when I try to use my 196 different explanatory variables.  Can anybody can tell me how deal with the segmented package or offer any other solution?

Comment: I think you are trying to work on a problem that is too difficult. If you have a single covariate and a single response finding a breakpoint in a line may not be too difficult but with 196 different variables allowed to change how could you even picture the shape of the response in such a high-dimensional space much less identify breakpoints!